# How to play live video streaming from remote url in android?

Tags: android, video, stream

I have create a one function which triggers a notification service at particular time interval.Notification can be of text,image or video...

Now,for video i download it first and then play it which takes more time...so is there any mechanism that i can play the video directly from remote url ???

Please help me ... 
i desperately need the answer asap...

Thanks in Advance ........

Have a look at my code snippets ::

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notificationvideo);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    //pd=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...", "Please Wait...",true,false);
    playVideo();
    //pd.dismiss();

    img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back); 
    img_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {          
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                Intent int_back=new Intent(NotificationsVideoActivity.this,MyChannelsActivity.class);
                startActivity(int_back);
                finish();
        }               
    });  
}

private void playVideo() 
{
    try {
         path = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(NotificationsVideoActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 
        else 
        {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) 
            {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) 
        {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}

private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException
{
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) 
    {
        return path;
    } 
    else 
    {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "mp4");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        //byte buf[] = new byte[8192];

        do 
        {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);

        try 
        {
            stream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this -

```
String path="http://www.ted.com/talks/download/video/8584/talk/761";
String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";

Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);

VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Comment: I have already tried this...can i increase the buffer size like this???? was it helpful to me ?????byte buf[] = new byte[8192];

Answer (score 0):

try webview and exmaple given at http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/downloads/list and complete source is at http://html5webview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ take as refrence and try what u want

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Video Please wait...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            video.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
            uri = Uri.parse("live streaming url");
            video.setVideoURI(uri);

video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                video.start();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```